# Is there a way to change the android:label but only via command line build?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We distribute our companies app to firebase, but we have a lot of different app flavors/variants. It gets confusing to have them all named the same `My Application`. The bundles show in firebase, but having to explain all the flavors to everyone by bundle takes too long.

Is there a way I could pass a command-line arg to change the name of the app only for these firebase builds? Otherwise, it is fine when they are named the same during development or deployment. That is why I do not want to permanently change the name.

To clarify, I am not asking how to permanently change the name of the app. I am asking how I might do something like this while deploying to firebase from a CI job. Basically a temporary state.

Was looking at just writing a simple bash script to change the name in the XML file using `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a nicer way, but doing this worked

```
sed -i -e 's#@string/app_name#appStaging#g' app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```